# Iteration over cursor with pymongo unreasonably slow

Tags: python, mongodb

### Context

I have a mongo database that has one collection called documents. This collection has 436333 entries and I have to do some operations on each of them. My code is:

```py
client = MongoClient()
db = client['database']
documents = db.documents.find()
bias = {
        'title': pd.DataFrame(index=POS_TAGS, dtype=np.int32),
        'abstract': pd.DataFrame(index=POS_TAGS, dtype=np.int32),
        'title_abstract': pd.DataFrame(index=POS_TAGS,     dtype=np.int32)}    
for i, doc in enumerate(documents):
    pos_tags = doc['agg_pos_tagging']
    for k, v in pos_tags.items():
        if len(v) != 0:
            bias[k].loc[:, doc["id"]] = \
                pd.Series(_match_values(v), index=POS_TAGS)
        else:
            bias[k].loc[:, doc["id"]] = \
                pd.Series([0] * len(POS_TAGS), index=POS_TAGS)
    if i % 10000 == 0:
       logging.info("{0} docs added".format(i))
```

I have CentOS 6.7 and mongodb 2.6. I'm using python 3.4, pymongo 3.2.2 (with c extensions installed) and pandas 0.18.0. The program and the server are in the same machine. The collection is indexed over its id.

### Problem

The problem is that the time it takes to pass for each chunck of 10000 entries increases with the amount of lines retrieved. This is the log:

```
2016-06-12 16:11:17,016 : INFO : 0 docs added
2016-06-12 16:13:45,553 : INFO : 10000 docs added
2016-06-12 16:17:47,117 : INFO : 20000 docs added
2016-06-12 16:23:14,786 : INFO : 30000 docs added
2016-06-12 16:29:40,412 : INFO : 40000 docs added
2016-06-12 16:38:11,807 : INFO : 50000 docs added
2016-06-12 16:50:38,987 : INFO : 60000 docs added
2016-06-12 17:04:19,188 : INFO : 70000 docs added
2016-06-12 17:18:21,669 : INFO : 80000 docs added
2016-06-12 17:34:18,687 : INFO : 90000 docs added
2016-06-12 17:53:11,497 : INFO : 100000 docs added
2016-06-12 18:18:57,503 : INFO : 110000 docs added
2016-06-12 18:51:33,503 : INFO : 120000 docs added
2016-06-12 19:24:47,799 : INFO : 130000 docs added
2016-06-12 19:57:40,690 : INFO : 140000 docs added
2016-06-12 20:31:44,103 : INFO : 150000 docs added
2016-06-12 21:10:24,900 : INFO : 160000 docs added
2016-06-12 22:02:46,849 : INFO : 170000 docs added
2016-06-12 22:57:50,108 : INFO : 180000 docs added
2016-06-12 23:55:52,541 : INFO : 190000 docs added
2016-06-13 00:56:43,676 : INFO : 200000 docs added
2016-06-13 02:07:39,460 : INFO : 210000 docs added
2016-06-13 03:22:43,074 : INFO : 220000 docs added
2016-06-13 04:40:00,819 : INFO : 230000 docs added
2016-06-13 06:05:09,572 : INFO : 240000 docs added
2016-06-13 07:27:09,148 : INFO : 250000 docs added
2016-06-13 08:58:45,093 : INFO : 260000 docs added
2016-06-13 10:13:26,832 : INFO : 270000 docs added
2016-06-13 11:30:29,821 : INFO : 280000 docs added
2016-06-13 12:53:54,008 : INFO : 290000 docs added
2016-06-13 14:20:45,617 : INFO : 300000 docs added
2016-06-13 16:01:00,446 : INFO : 310000 docs added
2016-06-13 17:40:26,558 : INFO : 320000 docs added
2016-06-13 19:30:14,056 : INFO : 330000 docs added
2016-06-13 21:19:33,698 : INFO : 340000 docs added
2016-06-13 23:10:49,665 : INFO : 350000 docs added
```

Adding the documents 340000 to 350000 takes almost two hours but adding the first 10000 takes only 2 minutes.

I don't think there is a problem with the calculations. They should take approximately the same amount of time for each chunck of 10000 items. I looked the log file of the database and it doesn't show all the `getMore` operations (I added all nreturns and it doesn't corresponds to the amount of documents retrieved), so I don't know if I should trust it.

I tried changing the `cursor_type` to `EXHAUST` but it didn't change the results.

What can I do to make it faster?

**EDIT**
I run the code without any calculation and so far I got this.

```
2016-06-14 15:43:19,263 : INFO : 0 docs added
2016-06-14 15:43:23,488 : INFO : 10000 docs added
2016-06-14 15:43:27,532 : INFO : 20000 docs added
2016-06-14 15:43:32,112 : INFO : 30000 docs added
2016-06-14 15:43:36,098 : INFO : 40000 docs added
2016-06-14 15:44:13,818 : INFO : 50000 docs added
2016-06-14 15:44:52,624 : INFO : 60000 docs added
2016-06-14 15:45:48,415 : INFO : 70000 docs added
2016-06-14 15:47:10,645 : INFO : 80000 docs added
2016-06-14 15:48:26,565 : INFO : 90000 docs added
2016-06-14 15:48:57,270 : INFO : 100000 docs added
2016-06-14 15:49:52,323 : INFO : 110000 docs added
2016-06-14 15:51:22,808 : INFO : 120000 docs added
2016-06-14 15:53:30,554 : INFO : 130000 docs added
2016-06-14 15:55:31,960 : INFO : 140000 docs added
```

There is still some lag that increases over time.

Comment: You say "I don't think there is a problem with the calculations", but you need to prove it to know for sure. So comment out all your calculations and see how long it takes to simply enumerate all the docs.

Comment: I just run the code without any calculation. It doesn't takes as long but there is still some lag. I put the results in the question